# Google Maps v3. Infowindow with jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-tabs, infowindow

I'm a beginner on Gmaps programming.

I want to create an InfoWindow containing two tabs, one of them just with infomation and the other one with some HTML-form (button and text).

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow/tabs.html

```
var checkText = "Coordinates";

var content = [
  '<div id="tabs">',
  '<ul>',
    '<li><a href="#tab_1"><span>One</span></a></li>',
    '<li><a href="#tab_2"><span>Two</span></a></li>',
  '</ul>',
  '<div id="tab_1">',
     '<p>Marker i:"</p>'+
     '<form id='button'>'+
       '<div>'+
         '<input type='submit' value='Submit' />'+
       '</div>'+
     '</form>',
  '</div>',
  '<div id="tab_2">',
    '<p>Info: '+checkText+'</p>',
  '</div>',
  '</div>'
].join('');
```

And then, the event listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
  infoWindow.setContent(content);
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

The tabs are perfectly showed and also the button, but I don't know how to associate it to an action, for example:

```
marker.draggrable = true;  // letting the marker to move
checkText =  marker.getPosition();  // changing the tab info whenever marker moves
```

I guess this issue is not related with jquery-tabs but with any infowindow with an html-form inside.
Thanks.

//-------------------------

I will simplify my question.

I have prepared this example where you can find a "button" in the infowindow:
  http://www.sipa.es/prueba_fer/index_prueba.html

How can I associate an action to that button?
For example, changing the zoom, open a new window, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The marker object has [drag events](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker):

- drag: This event is repeatedly fired while the user drags the marker.
- dragend: This event is fired when the user stops dragging the marker.
- draggable_changed: This event is fired when the marker's draggable property changes.
- dragstart: This event is fired when the user starts dragging the marker.

Then update your content when the event fires

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
    checkText = this.getPosition();
    content = [
        '<div id="tabs">',
                '<ul>',
                    '<li><a href="#tab_1"><span>One</span></a></li>',
                    '<li><a href="#tab_2"><span>Two</span></a></li>',
                '</ul>',
            '<div id="tab_1">',
                '<p>Marker i:"</p>'+
                '<form id="button">'+
                    '<div>'+
                        '<input type="submit" value="Submit" />'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</form>',
            '</div>',
                '<div id="tab_2">',
                    '<p>Info: '+checkText+'</p>',
                '</div>',
        '</div>'
    ].join('');  

});
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok, you need to make sure you catch the elements in the infowindow when they are attached to the DOM.  Infowindows have a `domready` event.  I updated the function in your example to show this.  Also, remember a postback will reset the map.  You did not say whether you need a post back or not, so I cancelled it using `e.preventDefault();`

```
(function () {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          draggable: false,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.30, -3.71)
     });
     var content = "<div id='tabs'>" +
                   "<form id='button'>" +
                   "<div>" +
                   "<input id='btn' type='submit' value='Submit'/>" +
                   "</div>" +
                   "</form>" +
                   "</div>";

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
            infoWindow.setContent(content);
            infoWindow.open(map, this);
            map.setCenter(this.getPosition());

     });    

     google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function (e) {
           //attach the click event to the button.
           document.forms.button.btn.onclick = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); //cancels the post back.
                var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
                map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel - 2); //zoom out two levels
            };    
     });   

})();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not my problem, I have added some clarifications and an example to my question...

Comment: Great, it works! Didn't know what a "postback" was, I'm not a programmer, and I need some time to assimilate some concepts. Thank you very much for your useful answer.